# Passing data to Custom Views and their children from a UITbleViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom view, let's call it `ArticleView`, that has three child views, which are also custom views, let's call them `CustomLabel` (they are a view with two labels each)

Each of my views can be either "light" or "dark" themed, depending on a boolean called "dark", that each custom view knows how to draw itself depending on it.

My questions is the following: I have a `UITableViewController`, and each `UITableViewCell` has an `ArticleView` inside of it. I do not want to expose the child subviews of the `ArticleView` to the cell, so in each cell (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) I pass the "dark" parameter to the `ArticleView`, which in turn passes the var to its children `CustomLabels` (via the `didSet{}` methods of swift), which in turn draw themselves accordingly.

Is this the correct pattern of passing data from my TableView's data all the way down to the custom child views of my custom view?

I do not want to let my cell have access to my `ArticleView's` children since that would make things less maintainable in the future. What is the best approach here? It just seems I'm passing the "dark" parameter too many times, so I'm asking if there is a better architectural approach for my case.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like the right approach to me.

Comment: Thanks for assuring me @Paulw11 I'll keep using this approach unless someone else has any suggestions.